# The definition of some macros in cl.h

Tags: c, opencl

I was trying to read `cl.h`, which is the header file for OpenCL. In this header file I found macros like

```
#define CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM                         0x1084
```

It seems to me that `0x1084` is an address in memory. But I'm not sure. Can anyone explain to me the meaning of this definition?

Comment: it's just a hexadecimal number (4228 in decimal), you probably think it's a memory address because these are usually also represented in a debugger for instance by hex numbers..

Comment: It's just a magic number. It doesn't have any special meaning (see the other constants, they are defined in ascending order).

Comment: This makes sense. Do you know why they use the hexadecimal number instead of the normal number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479061/why-are-constants-in-c-header-files-of-libraries-always-defined-as-hexadecimal

Comment: You should post your comments as an answer, seeing as it answers the question well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x1084` is just a number in hexadecimal representation (that's what the `0x` part does). There are a number of reasons developpers usually use hexadecimal number in definitions in headers, layed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479061/why-are-constants-in-c-header-files-of-libraries-always-defined-as-hexadecimal)

Debuggers usually also represent memory addresses using hexadecimal numbers which is likely why you thought at first the number shown was such an address.